# Can ecological momentary assessment (EMA) data be meta-analyzed?

Tags: panel-data, meta-analysis

**Summary: What would be the appropriate way to meta-analyze the association between momentary measures of two constructs (and is this even advised)?**

I'm wondering if it is possible to meta-analyze ecological momentary assessment (EMA, also referred to as experience sampling method or ESM) data. Specifically, I am working on a meta-analysis of the correlation between two constructs (let's say anxiety and depression). I would like to include in this set of analyses studies that measured anxiety and depression using the EMA method, which is an intensive longitudinal method that involves asking participants to report on their depression and anxiety in the moment on multiple occasions over time.

Is it possible to meta-analyze intensive longitudinal data? If so, what are the considerations? I'm aware that I would likely need to do a separate meta-analysis for the EMA studies (as opposed to the studies that measured depression and anxiety using traits questionnaires).

Some studies do report the correlation (Pearson's r) between EMA measures. However, I'm aware that EMA data should be handled using hierarchical methods because it is multi-level. Theoretically, I could ask authors to provide the relationship between their measures of anxiety and depression, derived using multi-level modeling to account for the fact that the data are nested within the participant.